# How to get values of dynamically generated text box and make ajax request to controller in mvc4 and jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one table where I am dynamically generating textbox's and binding model values to those textboxe's. Also i have one button. I want to send dynamically generated textbox values in Ajax request. My code is as below.

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in group.Items)
            {
                <th>@item.Label</th>
            }


        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in group.Items)
            {
                <td><input type="text" id="Value" value="@item.Value"></td>
            }

        </tr>


    </table>
            }
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    <tr>
        @{ int k = 1; }
        @foreach (var item in group.Items)
                {
                    if (k == 1)
                    {
                <td scope="col">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveUpdate" onclick="updatemetaData('@item.upld_id,@item.Value');">Save</button></td>
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```

this is my jquery function to make ajax request.

```
  function updatemetaData(docid) {
            $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "GET",
                     data: { upld_id: docid },
                     dataType: "html",
                     url: '/documentVerification/updatedocDetails',
                     headers: {
                         'VerificationToken': forgeryId
                  },
                     success: function (data)
                     {
                         $('#GridDetails').html("");
                         $('#GridDetails').html(data);
                         $("#dialog-formdocumentdata").dialog('open');

                     }
                       , error: function (error)
                       {
                       }
                 });

        }

</script>
```

I want to send values of dynamically generated textboxes in ajax call. In the below code 2 text boxe's will generate in all cases.

```
@foreach (var item in group.Items)
            {
                <td><input type="text" id="Value" value="@item.Value"></td>
            }
```

Is it possible in jquery to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Best keep it as simple as possible. You're passing random numbers from the controller. Just serialize the model (as JSON) and add to a viewbag object. You can store it to an hidden field which is easy to handle with jquery.

Comment: yes thats correct. Only two textboxes will generate got it.

Comment: Put your answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't spot a computer around. Be careful following code may contain errors.

Use nuget to import Newtonsoft Json assembly.

In the controller add:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

ViewBag.JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObjectContainingRandomNumbers);
```

In the view:

```
@Html.Hidden("inputID", Viewbag.JsonData)
```

Move jquery reference to the hidden field and things should work.